# Trying to run app in Iphone but pod install error: "No podspec found for "path_provider_foundation" error"

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, podfile

[No podspec found for `path_provider_foundation` in `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_foundation/darwin`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xdO5.png)

I wanted to run app in simulator I tried other apps too but same error in all
I think it is related to flutter cache related things
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing

```
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-RunnerTests`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_foundation` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_foundation/darwin`
[!] No podspec found for `path_provider_foundation` in `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_foundation/darwin`

/Users/abdurahim/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:14:in `block in fetch'
/Users/abdurahim/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Users/abdurahim/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:11:in `fetch'
/Users/abdurahim/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:997:in `fetch_external_source'
/Users/abdurahim/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:976:in `block (2 levels) in fetch_external_sources'
/Users/abdurahim/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:975:in `each'
/Users/abdurahim/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:975:in `block in fetch_external_sources'
/Users/abdurahim/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Users/abdurahim/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:974:in `fetch_external_sources'
/Users/abdurahim/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:118:in `analyze'
/Users/abdurahim/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
/Users/abdurahim/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Users/abdurahim/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Users/abdurahim/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Users/abdurahim/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
/Users/abdurahim/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/abdurahim/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Users/abdurahim/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/abdurahim/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/abdurahim/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/bin/pod:25:in `load'
/Users/abdurahim/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
```